# How to download non-image file(pdf,pptx,docx) from FirebaseStorage to internal storage of device in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-storage

I want to create a Download Button in my Xamarin.Forms which after it's clicked, the app will download a file(pdf/pptx/docx) from a specific URL from my FirebaseStorage to the internal storage of my Device, and also show the download process in the notification bar.

How can I archive this in Xamarin.Forms?

I have this button code below:

```
  private async void DownloadButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   var fc = new FirebaseStorage("appspot.com");
   var getFileUrl = await 
   fc.Child("NonImage").Child("Pdf").Child("test.pdf").GetDownloadUrlAsync();

   // what should I do next to archive what I described?
  }
```

Edit: I tried with HttpCient and WebClient, but i get some errors

HttpClient:

```
private async void HttpHelper()
 {
   var fc = new FirebaseStorage("appspot.com");

   var getFileUrl = await  fc.Child("Image") 
  .Child("User").Child("test.pdf").GetDownloadUrlAsync();

   string GetRootPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath 
  (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

   string Complete = Path.Combine(GetRootPath, "test.pdf");

   byte[] fileBytes = await _httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(new 
   Uri(getFileUrl));

   File.WriteAllBytes(Complete, fileBytes);
   File.ReadAllBytes(Complete);
 }
```

WebClient:

```
    private async void HttpHelper()
    {
      var fc = new FirebaseStorage(".appspot.com");

      var getFileUrl = await fc.Child("Image") 
      .Child("User").Child("test.pdf").GetDownloadUrlAsync();

      using (var client = new WebClient())
      {
        client.DownloadFile(getFileUrl, "test.pdf");
      }

    }
```

Errors get from executing both functions:

Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3014KB/6028KB, paused 84us total 21.880ms

[Surface] opservice is null false

Comment: if you have the url of the resource you want to download this should work the same as any other file download in C#.  `HttpClient` has multiple methods you can use to download a file

Comment: @Sir Jason, i tried your method but in the output window of VS always show this: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3(16KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3014KB/6028KB, paused 84us total 21.880ms
, but i don't get any error. It also does not show any download process in the notification bar too.

Comment: also this too: [Surface] opservice is null false

Comment: please [edit] your post to include the actual code you tried

Comment: @Sir Jason i have edited the code already, please kindly check

Comment: the "errors" you are talking about are fairly standard Android log messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the GetDownloadUrlAsync to get the download URL for a file.

```
 var getFileUrl = await  fc.Child("Image") 
    .Child("User").Child("test.pdf").GetDownloadUrlAsync();
```

And then use the DownloadManager to download the file from URL.

```
 DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
    request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
    request.SetDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Forms.Context, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "hello.jpg");
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.App.Application.DownloadService);
    dm.Enqueue(request);
```

The DownloadManager provides its own notification to track your download progress.